# apache log_level doesn't change

Tags: php, macos, apache

I have recently updated to php 7.3 on my mac using

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3
```

and configured the **httpd.conf** to load the new php7 module. everything works fine with no problem. except the **error_log**. my files are flooded with this:

```
[Thu Feb 21 11:52:00.811832 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2201] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 127.0.0.1:54738] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http:
[Thu Feb 21 11:52:00.812331 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2201] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 127.0.0.1:54738] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http:
[Thu Feb 21 11:52:00.812422 2019] [:debug] [pid 2201] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 127.0.0.1:54738] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths 
[Thu Feb 21 11:52:00.812455 2019] [:debug] [pid 2201] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 127.0.0.1:54738] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths 
[Thu Feb 21 11:52:00.812482 2019] [:debug] [pid 2201] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 127.0.0.1:54738] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths 
[Thu Feb 21 11:52:00.812509 2019] [:debug] [pid 2201] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 127.0.0.1:54738] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths 
[Thu Feb 21 11:52:00.812535 2019] [:debug] [pid 2201] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 127.0.0.1:54738] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths 
[Thu Feb 21 11:52:00.812561 2019] [:debug] [pid 2201] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 127.0.0.1:54738] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths 
[Thu Feb 21 11:52:00.812586 2019] [:debug] [pid 2201] mod_hfs_apple2.c(384): [client 127.0.0.1:54738] mod_hfs_apple: Final check co
[Thu Feb 21 11:52:00.812648 2019] [:debug] [pid 2201] mod_hfs_apple2.c(397): [client 127.0.0.1:54738] mod_hfs_apple: Allowing acces
```

I set the **LogLevel** to **info** in the httpd.conf and in httpd-vhosts.conf for my virtual hosts but nothing happends.

I don't know how to stop them.

Comment: I already set the `error_reporting(0);
ini_set("display_errors", "0");` @RiggsFolly

Comment: Oh my mistake. ___this is an Apache Module___ so `php.ini` will be irrelevant. Look in the `httpd.conf` file or maybe in a VHOST definition for parameters SPECIFIC to the Apache module

Comment: already did it in both files. `httpd.conf` and `httpd-vhost.conf` . nothing happened. @RiggsFolly